# How to install eigen 3.3 in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to install eigen 3.3 in the Ubuntu. I tried to download newest version of Eigen 3 (3.3) and install as following

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```

The output likes

```
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/src/Skyline/SkylineStorage.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/src/SparseExtra/RandomSetter.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/src/SparseExtra/MarketIO.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/src/SparseExtra/BlockOfDynamicSparseMatrix.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/src/SparseExtra/DynamicSparseMatrix.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/src/SparseExtra/MatrixMarketIterator.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/src/Splines/SplineFwd.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/src/Splines/SplineFitting.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/src/Splines/Spline.h
```

However, when I check the my current eigen version with `dpkg -p libeigen3-dev`, the output is

```
Package: libeigen3-dev
Priority: extra
Section: libdevel
Installed-Size: 3729
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Source: eigen3
Version: 3.2.0-8
Provides: libeigen2-dev
Depends: pkg-config
Suggests: libeigen3-doc, libmrpt-dev
Size: 494158
```

It shown my setup does not finish. How can I install the eigen version in my Ubuntu? Thank all

This is error when I compile with CmakeList.txt at [source code](https://bitbucket.org/infinitei/videoparsing)

```
-- ===============================================================
-- ============ Configuring CompileSettings  =====================
-- ===============================================================
-- ============= Look for required libraries =====================
-- Looking for Eigen Library with minimum version 3.2.90
-- Looking for Eigen via User Provided (or Cached) location
-- Eigen version 3.2.0 found in /usr/include/eigen3
CMake Warning at cmake/FindEigen.cmake:62 (message):
  Eigen version is less than requred version 3.2.90
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/FindEigen.cmake:73 (Eigen_Check_Version)
  CMakeLists.txt:23 (FIND_PACKAGE)


CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find Eigen (missing: EIGEN_VERSION_OK) (Required is at least
  version "3.2.90")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/FindEigen.cmake:74 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:23 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

Comment: Unless you take additional steps (such as using the `checkinstall` program in place of `make install`), the dpkg system will know nothing about programs installed from source in this way.

Comment: Sorry. What does it mean? How could I fix my issue. I surely that I did not install 3.3 version successfully

Comment: What makes you think it was unsuccessful? What does `pkg-config --modversion eigen3` say? What version do you actually get when you try to build stuff?

Comment: Because I run a source code which require the version of Eigen >=3.2.90 and it shown that my current version is still 3.2.0

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Eigen c++ is a header only library: you don't have to install it, you just download it, unzip it and link your code against it.

For example, if your code is in `my_favorite_cpp_folder`, you do:

```
cd my_favorite_cpp_folder
```

and, assuming your compiler is `gcc` and the eigen headers are in 
`/usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/` and the name of your source file 
is `my_favorite_cpp_source_file.cpp`, you compile and code and link it to the eigen headers by doing:

```
g++ -I /usr/local/include/eigen3/ my_favorite_cpp_source_file.cpp -o my_favorite_cpp_source_file
```

(from your code output posted above, the eigen headers are in `/usr/local/include/eigen3/` in your computer)

Comment: Thank you. However, I compile an open source code from cmake. It use the line to check Eigen 3 version `# Add Eigen dependencies
FIND_PACKAGE(Eigen 3.2.90 REQUIRED)`. I did not find any setting lib path in the CmakeList.txt

Comment: in any case your problem is not with installing eigen, it is with installing that open source library. You should put up the errors messages you get when installing that library in your question, those will be informative.

Comment: Yes. I updated the error and source link

Comment: do `gedit /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h`  look for the lines `#define EIGEN_WORLD_VERSION` to `#define EIGEN_MINOR_VERSION` copy and post those.

Comment: The output is `#define EIGEN_WORLD_VERSION 3
#define EIGEN_MAJOR_VERSION 2
#define EIGEN_MINOR_VERSION 10`   And notice that the author requires that "a C++ template library for linear algebra (Requires Eigen 3.3.x)"

Comment: so just remove  your current `/usr/local/include/eigen3`, download a more recent version of [eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)  unzip it, rename the new folder `eigen3` and put it in `/usr/local/include/`

Comment: Thank you. It looks worked. I follows your guide and go to include/eigen3 and create build folder then `make, sudo make install`.  Is it correct with the final output ? `-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/pkgconfig/eigen3.pc
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/eigen3/cmake/Eigen3Targets.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/eigen3/cmake/Eigen3Config.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/eigen3/cmake/Eigen3ConfigVersion.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/share/eigen3/cmake/UseEigen3.cmake`

Comment: I think so. At this point I still don't know what is that open source library (which uses eigen) that you are trying to install. Surely, there is a readme file in there with a minimal test example to run to check it all works. Take your time, check it all works and only then accept my answer (I will then edit the useful pieces from the comments in my answer).

Comment: Thanks. It worked now. My installed software just a project.

Comment: Thanks, @user2413, saved my day!

Answer (score 42):

For those simply requiring a reasonably recent version of [Eigen 3](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org) on Ubuntu and similar Debian-based distros (*...which is the common case*), installing the existing `libeigen3-dev` package suffices: *e.g.,*

```
sudo apt install libeigen3-dev
```

Manually downloading and installing Eigen 3 is probably overkill for most use cases.

Comment: Seems simple but failed for me :(

Comment: `libeigen3-dev` installs Eigen 3.2, he is asking for 3.3, so this answer is wrong if you need 3.3.

Comment: on Ubuntu 19.04  the package gives you 3.3.7 ... whereas when you install from src tree github.com/PX4/eigen  you get 3.3.90   as of 20190712

Answer (score 3):

After extracting the compressed folder check the INSTALL file. I used the second option of installing using `cmake`. After which "eigen3" folder with the header files was created in `/usr/local/include/` folder.

In your project you can include eigen headers like this:

```
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
```

I forgot to mention this. Since the header files are in `/usr/local/include/` folder you don't need to compile your source-code files against them using "`g++ -I` ....  ."

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

`dpkg` only knows about software that you have installed by Ubuntu's standard package management tools. But that's not how you installed eigen.
You have installed from the source code, and as such `dpkg` doesn't know it. The output of `dpkg -p libeigen3-dev` is not about the eigen that you installed, but about a different version of eigen, installed using the standard package management tools.

Based on your output of `sudo make install`,
the version of eigen that you installed from source is ready to use,
its files are available in `/usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/src`.