# Compiling code include Eigen library needs permission

Tags: permissions, c++

I just copy the Eigen folder to `/usr/local/include` according to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/860207/how-to-install-eigen-3-3-in-ubuntu-14-04), to use [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html) library.

Now to compile a simple example it needs to compile with sudo:

```
simple1.cpp:2:23: fatal error: /usr/local/include/Eigen/Dense: Permission denied
```

What's wrong? I think it should not ask for permission. Can I fix it?

**Edit**

I also changed the permission of folder to `drwxr-xr-x` and added

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/include/Eigen/"
```

and log out once. 
Still, I need permission to compile.

```
namei -lx /usr/local/include/Eigen/Dense
f: /usr/local/include/Eigen/Dense
Drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root usr
drwxr-xr-x root root local
drwxr-xr-x root root include
drwxr-xr-x root root Eigen
-rw-r--r-- root root Dense
```

Comment: Add the output of `namei -lx /usr/local/include/Eigen/Dense`, please

Comment: You say you tried to compile with `sudo`. What was the command used?

Comment: `g++ filename.cpp` ask me permission but `sudo g++ filename.cpp` worked.

Comment: Maybe I put the header files in another directory that need not permission  ,give the address by  `-I`  : `g++ file.cpp -I /to/library/address`.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? It looks like eigen3.3 is already available direct from the repository [File list of package libeigen3-dev in xenial](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/libeigen3-dev/filelist) - there should be no need to manually copy files to /usr/local. FYI the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable has nothing to do with header file locations.

Comment: Mint mate 18.1  serena , I installed the `libeigen3-dev`, it does not work.  it's strange